# Does a 90 ECTS Masters hurt your chances of PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, computer-science, masters-post-phd

Given that 120 ECTS Masters exist will opting for a 90 ECTS Masters program, part-time (taught & research) in Computer Science, greatly hinder your chances of securing a funded PhD position in a country which is not your home country? (I am an EU national and would apply in EU countries as well as Norway, UK, Canada, USA & Australia).

Comment: Are you currently applying for Masters programs and want to know whether the 90/120 ECTS makes a difference, or have you already completed your 90 ECTS Masters and you're applying for Ph.D. programs?

Comment: The former, I am currently applying for a masters program.